# Ao utilizar o comando .extend() no Python, como armazenar o resultado em um objeto novo?

Tags: python, lista

Considerando as listas:

```
lista1=["a","b","c","d"] 
lista2=[5,6,7,8]
```

Meu objetivo é obter uma nova lista que tenha os elementos dessas duas `['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 5, 6, 7, 8]`, mas preservando-as do jeito que estão.

Fazendo `lista3=[lista1,lista2]`, o que obtive é uma lista de listas `[['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'], [5, 6, 7, 8]]`,  o que não é do meu interesse.

Tentei fazer do seguinte modo:

```
lista4=lista1
lista4.extend(lista1)
print(lista4)
```

Resultado:

```
['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 5, 6, 7, 8]
```

Isso resultou naquilo que eu esperava. Mas ao pedir a `lista1` novamente, ela já não estava com a configuração inicial, mas sim com o mesmo resultado acima.

```
print(lista1)
```

```
['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 5, 6, 7, 8]
```

Eu pensei que usando `lista4=lista1` e usar `.extend()` na lista4, a `lista1` ficaria como definida no início. Alguém poderia me explicar por que isso ocorreu e se tem como contornar?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Basta concatenar as listas e atribuir em uma nova:

```
lista1 = ["a", "b", "c", "d"] 
lista2 = [5, 6, 7, 8]

lista4 = lista1 + lista2

print(lista1) # ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']
print(lista2) # [5, 6, 7, 8]
print(lista4) # ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 5, 6, 7, 8]
```

---

No seu caso não funcionou como esperado porque ao fazer `lista4 = lista1`, você fez com que `lista4` apontasse para a mesma lista que `lista1` aponta (pois as variáveis `lista1` e `lista4` são na verdade referências para a lista - elas não contém a lista em si, e sim uma referência para a mesma).

Fazendo uma analogia, imagine que `lista1` é uma folha de papel com o meu endereço escrito. Ao fazer `lista4 = lista1`, estou pegando outra folha de papel e escrevendo o mesmo endereço nela.

Ao fazer qualquer operação com essas folhas de papel (por exemplo, "entregue este pacote no endereço que está escrito aí"), tanto faz se ela é feita em `lista1` ou `lista4`. Como ambas apontam para o mesmo endereço, o resultado será o pacote entregue na minha casa.

Da mesma forma, ao fazer `extend` em `lista4`, isso modifica a lista para a qual `lista4` está apontando. E como ela aponta para a mesma lista que `lista1`, esta é modificada.

Já ao concatenar as listas com `+`, você está criando uma nova lista, mantendo as originais intactas.

Comment: Eu estou habituado a usar o software R e ele aceita esse tipo de operação, por isso fiquei um pouco perdido. 
Muito obrigado pela explicação! Foi muito didática!